# I removed the sudo,the I have no permission to install any program?

Tags: linux, sudo, root

It's seems like a big problem. I can't login as root, because I use the fedora20, and I can not use `sudo`. What can I do now ?

Comment: [su authentication failure, sudo missing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152525/su-authentication-failure-sudo-missing)

Comment: @DavidPostill right! use pkexec works

Answer (score 0):

#### su authentication failure, sudo missing

> You can use `pkexec yum install sudo`. pkexec will let you enter your password in your OS's GUI.
>
> pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user.
> If username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the
> administrative super user, root.
>
> This helped:
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/434525/can-sudo-be-reinstalled-after-being-removed

Source https://unix.stackexchange.com answer [su authentication failure, sudo missing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152528/95111) by [portOdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/82229/portodin)